# Ajax no success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a form validation using Ajax, so this is what I got so far:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../includes/loginSystem.php",
        data: "username=" + username + "&password=" + password,
        beforeSend: function () {
            alert("LOADING....");
        },
        success: function (html) {
            alert("success!");
            if (html.split(",")[0] == "true") {
                sessionStorage.setItem("loggedIn", true);
                loginEr.html("null");
                alert("true!");
                $("#login-modal").modal("hide");
                $("#navbar-nav2").html("<button id='profileBtn5' class='btn btn-default' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#profile-modal'><?php echo " + html.split(",")[1] + "; ?></button>")
            } else if (html.split(",")[0] == "false") {
                sessionStorage.setItem("loggedIn", false);
                loginEr.html(LOGIN_FAIL);
                alert("false!");
            }
        }
    });
```

Is there something wrong with it? Because it always shows me the beforeSend content and doesn't do anything about success..

Comment: What does your browser say?

Comment: do you see anything in the network tab of your js developer tools or, anything being seen in your server's log files about an incoming connection?

Comment: No, I don't see anything...

Comment: GreenCube, have you tried to implement an error/failure function for the ajax and see what is coming back from the service?

Answer (score -1):

The correct [syntax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) should be:

```
...
data: {username: username, password: password},
...
```

Comment: The OP's `data:` object is serialized and is valid syntactically.